# JQuery's Lightbox wont fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, lightbox

I work with ASP.NET MVC 3.
I have a child page that inherits a master page which loads the jQuery Lightbox scripts for displaying images on a popup. I have followed the example from [here](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/) .
The images are loaded correctly (I can see the thumbnails just like in the example from that site) but when I click on one of them, I get redirected to a page with only that image, and no popup appears.
The scripts (from jquery, jquery.lightbox, the css needed ) are all loaded correctly (I debug with Firebug and I can see them in the head of the page source).

What should I do to get the popup effect? (I'ved also added the function that applies the lightbox on a div containing the photo gallery `$('#gallery a').lightBox();` just like in the example but stil nothing).

**EDIT**

The sample code from master page:

```
script src="<%=Html.Resolve("/Content/MediaHelpers/js/jquery.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

" type="text/css" media="screen"/>

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Item_StartDate").datepicker();
        $("#Item_EndDate").datepicker();
        $("#Item_CheckInDate").datepicker();
        $("#Item_CheckOutDate").datepicker();
        $("#Item_DepartTime").datepicker();
        $("#Item_ArrivalTime").datepicker();
        $("#Item_PickUpDate").datepicker();
        $("#Item_DropOffDate").datepicker();
        $('#gallery a').lightBox();
    });
```

The Html.Resolve works well since I can see them loaded on the web page when running the site.

The child page has exactly the code from the lightbox example:

```
<div id="gallery">
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="photos/image1.jpg" title="Utilize a flexibilidade dos seletores da jQuery e crie um grupo de imagens como desejar. $('#gallery').lightBox();">
            <img src="photos/thumb_image1.jpg" width="72" height="72" alt="" />
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="photos/image2.jpg" title="Utilize a flexibilidade dos seletores da jQuery e crie um grupo de imagens como desejar. $('#gallery a').lightBox();">
            <img src="photos/thumb_image2.jpg" width="72" height="72" alt="" />
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="photos/image3.jpg" title="Utilize a flexibilidade dos seletores da jQuery e crie um grupo de imagens como desejar. $('#gallery a').lightBox();">
            <img src="photos/thumb_image3.jpg" width="72" height="72" alt="" />
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="photos/image4.jpg" title="Utilize a flexibilidade dos seletores da jQuery e crie um grupo de imagens como desejar. $('#gallery a').lightBox();">
            <img src="photos/thumb_image4.jpg" width="72" height="72" alt="" />
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="photos/image5.jpg" title="Utilize a flexibilidade dos seletores da jQuery e crie um grupo de imagens como desejar. $('#gallery a').lightBox();">
            <img src="photos/thumb_image5.jpg" width="72" height="72" alt="" />
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks in advance,
Tamas

Comment: Are you initializing the lightbox on document.ready?  without a sample its hard to 'guess', but perhaps you are initializing the lightbox before DOM is ready (before the items are on the page).  Therefore nothing is being initialized.

Comment: I have added code samples from the web pages.

Comment: The html sample is mine (not generated).

Comment: see my answer below.  I believe this will solve your issue.

Comment: Tried also $('#gallery').lightBox(); on document load, but still same results.

Comment: updated answer with working version on jsFiddle, see below

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808935/display-image-using-lightbox-using-mvc

Answer (score 0):

Your html mark-up could look like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="gallery">
        <a href="photos/image1.jpg" title="Utilize a flexibilidade dos seletores da jQuery e crie um grupo de imagens como desejar.">
            <img src="photos/thumb_image1.jpg" width="72" height="72" alt="" />
        </a>
        <a href="photos/image2.jpg" title="Utilize a flexibilidade dos seletores da jQuery e crie um grupo de imagens como desejar.">
            <img src="photos/thumb_image2.jpg" width="72" height="72" alt="" />
        </a>
        <a href="photos/image3.jpg" title="Utilize a flexibilidade dos seletores da jQuery e crie um grupo de imagens como desejar.">
            <img src="photos/thumb_image3.jpg" width="72" height="72" alt="" />
        </a>
        <a href="photos/image4.jpg" title="Utilize a flexibilidade dos seletores da jQuery e crie um grupo de imagens como desejar.">
            <img src="photos/thumb_image4.jpg" width="72" height="72" alt="" />
        </a>
        <a href="photos/image5.jpg" title="Utilize a flexibilidade dos seletores da jQuery e crie um grupo de imagens como desejar.">
            <img src="photos/thumb_image5.jpg" width="72" height="72" alt="" />
        </a>
</div>
```

Doc Ready JS:

```
$('#gallery a').lightBox();
```

Working example [**HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/puMxR/)

Comment: Tried this too. Same results. The [example] (http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/) works well and is the same html I use.

Comment: for working example I added text to the links because I did not want to dig up thumbnails and images off the web to reference for the demo, but this shows how it works and how it needs to be set up.

Comment: You can download the zip from the example link. I works that for me too but in my MVC application that is just like the example, it does not fire the popup although all scripts + css were correctly loaded.